# python insert certain data from other csv to new csv (column as base to compare)

Tags: python, csv

I wan to insert a certain row from 2nd.csv to 1st.csv with respect to it's column.

here are my files

1st.csv

```
store_name_id   seller_name    date_hired   age
100             jed            2014/0707    33
200             ej             2014/0708    33
200             charm          2014/0709    11
111             teahaa         2014/0710    22
111             luis           2014/0711    12
200             jess           2014/0712    66
```

2nd.csv

```
ID     Store_Name     Store_description           contacts
100    new store      newly build store           1313134
200    young store    the owner is young           1111111
111    pretty store   the owner is pretty cool     1231331
```

here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

d = {}

with open("1st.csv", 'rb') as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    d[row[0]] = row

with open("2nd.csv", 'rb') as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    old_row = d.setdefault(row[0], [row[0]])
    old_row[4:] = row[1:]

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
  csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t').writerows(d.values())
```

but the output is:

some how like this (not actual):

```
100   jed      2014/0707    33
100   new store newly build store   1313134
200   ej       2014/0708    33
200   young store   the owner is young  1111111
200   charm    2014/0709    11
111   teahaa    2014/0710   22
111   luis     2014/0711    12
111   pretty store  the owner is pretty cool    1231331
```

they merge yes but my expected and want output must be like this

```
store_name_id   seller_name date_hired  age Store_name  Store_description   contacts
100              jed         2014/0707  33  new store   newly build store   1313134
200               ej         2014/0708  33  young store the owner is young  1111111
200             charm        2014/0709  11  young store the owner is young  1111111
111             teahaa       2014/0710  22  pretty store    the owner is pretty cool    1231331
111             luis         2014/0711  12  pretty store    the owner is pretty cool    1231331
200             jess         2014/0712  66  young store the owner is young  1111111
```

I'm still new and learning this language. please help.

---

like this output

```
store_name_id   seller_name date_hired  age Store_name  Store_description   contacts
100              jed         2014/0707  33  new store   newly build store   1313134
200               ej         2014/0708  33  young store the owner is young  1111111
111             teahaa       2014/0710  22  pretty store    the owner is pretty cool    1231331
```

it just get a single data, rest with same store_name_id was gone.

Comment: Are you sure your 1st.csv and 2nd.csv are `','` delimited?

Comment: yes i can make them comma separated or tab separated, and yes they are "," delimited

Comment: What are you expecting if the row is not there in 1st.csv , but is there in 2nd.csv ?

Comment: So the issue you are getting is that output csv is completely out of order right?

Comment: leave it blank maybe like,  " "," "," "," ", "storename","sofort","so-on".. like this sir.

Comment: yes sir instead to create a column, it insert on the row next to the pattern it gets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue you are getting is that the output csv is completely out of order. That is because dictionary does not have any sense of order, so the result of `d.values()` would most of the times be in arbitrary order.

So instead of using a dictionary, use a list to store, and maybe a dictionary to point to the index of that row.

According to comments, it seems like you are also reading the file in wrong order , you need to read b first, make a list of its stores and then read a and create the output list.

Example -

```
import csv

d = {}
lst = []
with open("b.csv", 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  header = next(reader)[1:]
  for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    d[row[0]] = i
    lst.append(row)

newlst = []
with open("a.csv", 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  head = next(reader)
  head.extend(header)
  newlst.append(head)
  for row in reader:
    idx = d.get(row[0], -1)
    if idx != -1:
        old_row = lst[idx]
        row.extend(old_row[1:])
    else:
        row = row + ["","","",""]
    newlst.append(row)



with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
  csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t').writerows(newlst)
```

Comment: man your awesome ^this code helps me a lot! thank thanks +rep

Comment: glad I could be helpful :)

Comment: i found something wrong, when it found a match, it ignores the other matches, it just get the first match and put details on it, rest (store_name_id   seller_name    date_hired   age) was gone . pls help @ arnand

Comment: output was below this answer

Comment: same case sir, when a duplicate of store_name_id match at first time, ignore others. :(

Comment: Ok, small issue was there, check now.

Comment: must also include this code old_row = [row[0],"","","","","","",""] on the else condition, this code states when there is no match add details still in row

Comment: Ok added that as well.